# Limit number of districts touched by each vehicle in ortools VRP

Tags: routes, constraints, or-tools

I need to keep it short because of my bad english :)

Let's say I have to solve a simple VRP on a city with multiple districts and I want to limit the maximum number of ditricts touched by each vehicle/route.

Orders=[(x1,y1),(x2,y1),(x3,y3)...(xN,yN)] # each order is identified by its coordinates

Districts=[1,2,3] # only 3 districts for simplicity

Order_district=[2,3,2,...1] # orders belong to one of three districts

My first thought was to add a penalty for each "touched district", but it's hard for me to define a correct Disjunction.

Another option would be to define a dimension based on the length of the Set of  touched districts (ie the number of distinct district the route touches), but again how to define such a Dimension?

Any hint?
Thanks

EDIT:

I realized that it must be a hard constraint and tried with the following:

```
traversed_zones=[]
for v in all_vehicles:
    traversed_zones.append([[]]*len(all_zones))
for p in all_points:
    z=zones[p]
    traversed_zones[v][z].append(model.VehicleVar(manager.NodeToIndex(p))==v) #True if the vehicle v serves the point p
# sum 1 for all zones with at least one point served by the vehicle v
solver.AddConstraint( solver.Sum(1 for z in traversed_zones[v] if solver.Sum(z)>0) < 3)
```

but running it I get no solution.
I tried a lot of variation of this approach but with no success

Any help or usefull example of using such a derived constraint?
Thank you all!

Answer (score 3):

I found my error.
It was a stupid bug in the way my collection was initialized!
I'm reporting it here just in case anyone was interested in (one) correct solution of the problem:

```
    traversed_zones={}
    for v in all_vehicles:                           
        traversed_zones[v]={}
        for p in all_points:
            if p>=data['cluster_depots']: # depot's zone doesn't matter
                z=data['cluster_zones'][p]
                zone_list=traversed_zones[v].get(z,None)
                if zone_list==None:
                    zone_list=[]
                    traversed_zones[v][z]=zone_list
                # vehicle(p)==v -> v serves p in zone z
                zone_list.append(model.VehicleVar(manager.NodeToIndex(p))==v)

        #sum(max([True for p in points of zone z if vehicle v serves p])) -> counts the served zones
        constraint=(solver.Sum(solver.Max(z) for z in traversed_zones[v].values())<=conf['zones_limit'])
        solver.AddConstraint(constraint)`
```